# Debug XCode LD Linker Command Failed 1 File Not Found: /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I get this error while linking a very complex project, and I need to know the best way to debug it.

I have turned on the following environment variables for ld:

```
export RC_TRACE_ARCHIVES=1
export RC_TRACE_DYLIBS=1
export RC_TRACE_PREBINDING_DISABLED=1
```

And added the -t -whyload -whatsloaded options to ld.

The last messages from ld are:

```
[Logging for XBS] Used indirect dynamic library: /Applications/Xcode6-
    Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/
    SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/
    System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is a general question about how to debug this error, but specifically, I am using XCode 6 beta 4.  That might be the cause of the error.  I need to use XCode 6 for its dynamic framework capability.

Does anyone know what libFosl_dynamic.dylib is?  Can anyone provide information about how to determine what object module, static library or other dylib triggered the requirement for this libFosl_dynamic.dylib module to load?

I grep'ed in the derived data directory:

```
/Users/"user"/Library/Developer/Xcode/
    DerivedData/EngineSdkDemo-gbkxniqxsljcxybhbszrwqyrzdwq
```

and found the file "app"_dependency_info.dat.  That file apparently holds the list of libraries that will be loaded, leading up to the library that can't be found.  The last entries in that file are:

```
...
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/
    iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/
    Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
    EngineSdkDemo-gbkxniqxsljcxybhbszrwqyrzdwq/Build/Products/
    Debug-iphoneos/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
<Library search path 1>/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
<Library search path 2>/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
<Library search path 3>/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
<Library search path 4>/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
<Library search path 5>/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
...
```

Apparently ld is searching through all of my Library Search Paths in an attempt to locate that file, but it doesn't exist anywhere on my Mac.

(8/3/14) More:  I grep'ed in the XCode 6 beta 4 iOS 8 frameworks folder:

```
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer
    /Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
    /SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

I found a hit in coreimage.framework.  The great tool MacDepencencies 
[(here)](http://code.google.com/p/macdependency) listed the dependency to /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib.  Apparently this is a bug in XCode 6 beta 4.  That dylib is not included in the distribution.

(8/3/14) More:  I finally found one of the libFosl_dynamic.dylib files.  It was buried in the XCode iOS 8 SDK folders:

```
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer
    /Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
    /iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/usr/lib
```

I copied the file to /usr/lib.

Now that the file itself is not missing, I get the following new error from the linker:

```
ld: in '/usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib', missing required architecture armv7 in file
    /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib (2 slices) for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

(8/3/14): More:  That particular file in the iOS 8 SDK only supports i386 and X86-64 architectures.

(8/3/14) More: Of course it only supports i386 and X86-64 architectures!  I just noticed that the file is from the iPhoneSimulator.platform.  The file is missing in the corresponding iPhoneOS.platform folders.

(8/3/14) More: The file does not exist in the XCode 5.1.1 version of the iPhoneOS.platform files (simulator or device).  It appears in XCode 6 Beta 2 (simulator only), which is the first XCode 6 Beta version that I have.  So apparently, this issue was introduced with XCode 6.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Does `/usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib` exist?  Does it contain code for the `armv7` arch (use `lipo`)?

Comment: Thanks Droppy.  No, that file doesn't exist in /usr/lib, /lib, or /usr/local/lib.  I don't recognize it as one of my files.  Googling shows a couple of hits, but no information about what that file is.  I need to know how to determine which other module reference causes it to be loaded.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've run into this issue myself and am at a loss how to fix it. I have found a rather simple repro case for this:
1. Create new iOS Project
2. Add "-force_flat_namespace" to Other Linker Flags in Build Settings
3. Build for an iOS device (not the simulator!)
4. BUG!

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing the same issue for the past two days! @LambdaKnight